# Can I use Leaflet Draw to add layers to overlay layers?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Is it possible to add a "target overlay" for Leaflet Draw toolbar?
For example I could have two overlays such as Areas and Points of interest.
Now, I would like to add markers only to Points of Interest overlay and polygons on Areas overlay.

I've been trying to figure out that is it somehow possible to programmatically activate overlays or assign overlay for different draw toolbars but nothing seems to help.
All new layers are added to same overlay since I can't figure out which overlay toolbar is used.

And at least console log value of events don't seem to help and I cannot figure out that which toolbar was used (I could use it to force addLayer to use certain overaly), I cannot get anything regarding the target layer etc.

```
 var poiLayer = new L.FeatureGroup();
var areaLayer = new L.FeatureGroup();

var options = {
  polygon: {
    allowIntersection: false,
    drawError: {
      color: "#e1e100",
      message: "<strong>Lines of a polygon cannot overlap!</strong>"
    },
    shapeOptions: {
      color: "#FF5656"
    }
  },
  polygon: {
    allowIntersection: false,
    drawError: {
      color: "#e1e100",
      message: "<strong>Lines of a polygon cannot overlap!</strong>"
    },
    shapeOptions: {
      color: "#FF5656"
    }
  },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: areaLayer,
    poly: {
      allowIntersection: false
    },
    poly: {
      allowIntersection: false
    },
    poly: {
      allowIntersection: false
    }
  },
  draw: {
    featureGroup: areaLayer,
    name: "dafuq2",

    polygon: {
      allowIntersection: false,
      showArea: true
    },


  },
  name: "namne123123123"
};

//same for the poiLayer

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
map.addControl(drawControl);

var drawControl2 = new L.Control.Draw(options2);
map.addControl(drawControl2);
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {

  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: The Draw control adds / edits layers in a L.FeatureGroup (which you specify) - you can control how that L.FeatureGroup is displayed on a map. It doesn't interact with an overlay layer directly.

Comment: I added a code example. The last 4 lines are the problem since I cannot determine that which toolbar was used nor to which layer/featuregroup it concerns. I should be able determine this in order to call ´poiLayer.addTo(map);´ or ´areaLayer.addTo(map);´

Comment: Have you tried using the layeradd event on the FeatureGroup?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it didn't trigger any events. However, I tried 'layeradd' event which actually triggered if I added e.layer.addTo(poiLayer); to current code in the L.Draw.Event.CREATED block. Still, cannot create new layers/features per overlay layer.

Comment: I'm now using e.layer.option.color key in map.on('add',...)to determine that what is being added and into which layer this new layer should be added.
This seems like really hackish and unstable way to do this.